# When is $example[n] undef for @example in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

A consistent problem I run into when scripting is the return of use of uninitialized value "x" in 'y'.  This most frequently occurs when I attempt to take a specific value from a previously defined array.  An example can be found below:

```
my $in = $ARGV[0];

open $in, '<', 'input.txt';

for my $i ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    my @line = ( split ' ', <$in> );
    if ( $line[0] ne qw(Temperature) ) {
        next;
    } else {
        print "$line[1]\n";
    }
}
```

I have determined that the data is being input into the @line array through a print command, but cannot understand why I am unable to call the first and second items within that array.

EDIT:
Input file format:
    Average Values for the last   100 out of      100 Dynamics Steps

```
Simulation Time              0.1000 Picosecond
Total Energy                59.7313 Kcal/mole   (+/-   1.9942)
Potential Energy           -68.6523 Kcal/mole   (+/-   3.9487)
Kinetic Energy             128.3835 Kcal/mole   (+/-   3.8432)
Intermolecular            -199.2242 Kcal/mole   (+/-   1.7462)
Temperature                  124.12 Kelvin      (+/-     3.72)
```

Repeat x10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't assume that your file will always have 10 lines of input.  Instead iterate on the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#my $in = $ARGV[0];

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt';

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    last if $. > 10;

    my @cols = split ' ', $line;

    next if $cols[0] ne 'Temperature';

    print "$cols[1]\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mob.  Sorry, was just a little slow in editing.  Silly race conditions.  Would be nice if SO let oen know if someone else has a post opened for edit, and who it is. :)

Comment: Thanks for the while instruction.  It was still giving me some uninitialized value prompts so I incorporated Neil's answer of next unless ( @line ). This removes all errors but unfortunately nothing prints... I will put the input file format in the op.

Comment: If there is no reason for you to be limiting to just 10 lines of your file, you can remove the first line of this while loop.  Perhaps that's why you aren't seeing results.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it.  The 1..10 in op was an arbitrary number as I did not want to fill my terminal with thousands of errors. Removing the last if $. > 10; allows the script to function as intended.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You print the line, but you don't know that the array is defined.

```
my @line = ( split ' ', <$in> );
next unless ( @line )
if ( $line[0] ne qw(Temperature) ) {
        next;
    } else {
        print "$line[1]\n";
    }
```

Miller's answer is also valid; your use of the file handle is non-conventional.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, next unless is quite useful.